# Api method response go back after ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I have shared service and method that get data from an API

this is my method for repository.service

```
  public getRepertoireByDay(idDay: number) {
    return this.http.get(RepertoireService.REPERTOIRE_URL + 
                               RepertoireService.REPERTOIRE_BY_DAY + idDay);
  }
```

**App.component**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.repertoireService.getRepertoireByDay(new 
                 Date().getDay()-1).subscribe(res => {
      this.repertoireService.repertoire = res;
    });
```

And In other component I have

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.repertoire = this.repertoireService.repertoire;
  }
```

and all work fine, problem starting when i refresh page and now this component is render.

I call this method in app.component and initialize my variable, allways working fine when i click nav button and routing is changed i have data that was loaded in app.component problem started when i refresh page and view is rendered faster that data go back from Api and i have error that null or undefinded

Comment: Please share the code where the variables are initialized.

Comment: Insufficient code. Can you please make a demo at stackblitz.com

Comment: You don't you just directly use this.repertoireService.repertoire in another component, instead of assigning it in other?

Comment: @Prachi i try use this method in component but view is render faster than api response go back and i have null or undifned